# Error removing file: Permission denied

Tags: delete

I installed  soft PhotoRec and recovery some files after I want to delete but i cant 
how can I delete this files and folders? can somebody help me I am new user. 
“recup_dir.1” can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it immediately?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 3):

First , open a terminal `ctr+alt+t` and type `gksudo nautilus` . It will open a new file-browser window. Now go to your directory and delete it. ( you might want to search your directory under `Computer -> home -> username` , here username is your username.

Answer (score 0):

You can also can use terminal in this case by typing just 
`sudo rm -rf <directory>`

Comment: That's why I have written ` if it asks for permissions you have to give permission to it.`

Comment: Okay I will edit it. Thanks for pointing it out. :)